No pipe found with name 'X' inconsistently (and is declared)
I have installed a new laptop with the software and now VS Code can't read the pipes any more. My colleague has the same applications with their versions installed and is able to run the Angular project without problems.
This is not a problem with the declarations. As mentioned, it was working perfectly fine on my old laptop and on the laptop of my colleague. If I run the project, all is looking good, all pipes are working as expected.
The strange thing is that not all pipes are recognised, some do, some do not...

Line 15: No problem with the translate pipe
Line 16: No problem with the translate pipe
Line 18: translate pipe not recognised
... and more, see the errors (it is not only the translate pipe, but is used most in our projects


Things I tried:

Reinstalling Node versions (so I was on the same version as my colleague)
Removing the complete project on the disk including their dependencies/packages

Versions that we (my colleague and I) have installed:
Visual Studio Code

Angular CLI

Nodes in nvm
    20.11.0
  * 16.20.2 (Currently using 64-bit executable)

Windows (only my computer-version)

All help is appreciated 

Hello Naren,
Thank you for the response, but that is no solution. If I do have an error, I can't see this between the numerous other errors that are popping up.
Greetings, Krant

I have found the solution: Apparently it was the VS Code extension Angular Language Service (from Angular themselves) which was causing these problems.
When the extension is disabled I had no errors and enabling it back again the errors popped up.
I installed previous versions (up to 11.2.14) in the hope that I get rid of the errors, but no luck. When updating to the newest and reloading the extension: it was fixed!
No problems have been detected in the workspace. is a good thing to see. And I can also view more info when hovering on the translate pipe:

Hopefully other people can apply this solution for them as well.
Greetings,
Krant

The issue might be related to another error. First, try to resolve the other problems (ngModel & bsConfig).
If that doesn’t help, try clearing your Angular cache:

Close your IDE
Run ng cache clean
Delete the .angular folder in your project directory
Delete the node_modules folder
Run npm install
Restart the project and see if it has helped

If none of these steps work, please post more of your code (Module, Component).

I removed the entire project (again) and reinstalled Visual Studio Code. Unfortunately no results. I have errors popping up in every file that I open. As mentioned before: everything runs and module/components are loaded correctly. I just get multiple errors in the project which is very annoying.

Can you post all errors? Recently had a similar problem because there was a issue in the module.

Issue is on that same time solved (see my post). Even still, thank you for the help .
